# Collection become undefined after deploy on Meteor.com

Tags: javascript, deployment, collections, meteor

On my computer it's work well. After deploying on meteor.com I get error.
Creating collection look like this ( /lib/collections/messages.js )

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection('messages');
```

On browser console after input

```
Messages.insert({})
```

I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Messages is not defined
```

Comment: I can't say anything except that that shouldn't happen. Sure you've told us all the details?

Comment: `Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages");` this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very likely you have a syntax error somewhere in your code.

If you check up your browser console the syntax error is visible.

On your localhost the files are not concatenated into one single js file, so if there is an error somewhere, then the issue isn't too bad & your app will run fine, mostly.

The thing is when your entire project is concatenated into one single js file then when there is an error higher up in your code, the downstream code will not execute. So the code at `/lib/collections/messages.js` does not run & this is why it is not defined.

The error is likely to be something like `cannot read null of undefined` or `uncaught reference error` or something like that. If you solve whatever is causing this error and redeploy your app.

Comment: I don't what that will give that problem. I had another error. After fixed the error and changed `Messages = new Meteor.Collection('messages');` on `Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages");`. Now, all work right, thank you.